# ajax javascript data not display in zend framework And display error

Tags: zend-framework

I want fetch data from database using ajax/javascript in zend framework. but the error is display..

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message
>   'script 'attendancelist/monthleave.html' not found in path
>   (./application/views/scripts/)' in
>   /var/www/html/projects_prolive/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:988
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/projects_prolive/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(884):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->_script('attendancelist/...') #1
>   /var/www/html/projects_prolive/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(900):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->render('attendancelist/...') #2
>   /var/www/html/projects_prolive/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(921):
>   Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('attendancelist/...',
>   NULL) #3
>   /var/www/html/projects_prolive/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(960):
>   Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render() #4
>   /var/www/html/projects_prolive/library/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277):
>   Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch() #5
>   /var/www/html/projects_prolive/library/Zend/Controller in
>   /var/www/html/projects_prolive/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php on line
>   988

How to Fix It??

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable your layout with

`$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
$this->view->layout()->disableLayout();`